# In a Map Reduce Program Can we use a datastructure as the value?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have already recognized the key for the program can i use a data-structure such as a javabean to store 2 types.

**Example:**

 class JavaBean  
{

`private String s;`

`private int count;`

}

Can I use the above JavaBean as a value in my Hadoop Map-Reduce program?
Can you suggest what other data structure i can use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use JavaBean as Value. Like if you have POJO class:

```
Class JavaBean{
private String s;
private int count;
private String s;
private int count;
public String getS() {
    return s;
}
public void setS(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String toString(){
    return getS()+","+getCount();
}
```

In your Mapper Code first call the setter method of JavaBean class and emit value as toString() method of JavaBean like:

```
  JavaBean jb = new JavaBean();
  jb.setS("abc");
  jb.setCount(1);
  context.write(key,jb.toString());
```